# Not the version that should be when installing Anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, installation, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

I have installed Anaconda 4.3.1, Python 3.6, on my Ubuntu. Now when i run Python it is saying that the version is 2.7 and not 3.6 as i wanted it to be. and there is no mention to Anaconda beside the version. I am quite sure that i installed Anaconda the right way. What could i do?

Comment: You should remove the javascript tag since this question is not related javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check which python your system is using:

```
which python
```

If it is showing the system python you need to export the path to Anaconda in your ~/.bashrc file:

```
export PATH="/home/username/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

After you save the file you can activate the PATH:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

This will then always use Anaconda when you launch a new terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `python3` in your terminal instead of `python`. This should start the python 3.X interpreter.

Note that other scripts like `pip` also have an equivalent `pip3` for python 3.X.